# C# new in method declaration

Tags: c#

```
public new int AdjustedBaseValue
```

What does the new here mean or do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means you are shadowing the int value. It is declared in a base class and you are re-declaring it in a derived class, effectively hiding the base class version.

See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#the-new-modifier) for more information.

Refer example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

Answer (score 7):

In this case, `new` is a modifier that hides an inherited member from the base class. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier#:%7E:text=The%20new%20modifier%20creates%20a,inherited%20member%20generates%20a%20warning.).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good forum post with some examples between the differences of using `new` vs `override`

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/65e02299-300f-4b74-8f0a-679f490605f5

Answer (score 0):

New is to hiding the baseclass implementation. Stoping the polymorphism...