# Difference between new and override in below scenario

Tags: c#, oop

I have code below -

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public virtual void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is class 1");
        }
    }
```

And

```
   public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public override void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is class 2");
        }
    }
```

Now if I am calling -

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class2();
        obj.Test1();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Result : Method from Class2 is called.

But now I change code with `New` keyowrd

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is class 1");
        }
    }
```

and

```
   public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public new void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is class 2");
        }
    }
```

And calling the same way as I am calling above -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class2();
            obj.Test1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But result is different, Result : method from Class1 is called.

Question 1 : Why result changed while using `New` keyword.

Question 2 : what actually this line of code is doing 
 `Class1 obj = new Class2();`

I understand it is creating the object but then how it is different from

`Class1 obj = new Class1();`

The above scenario has confused me a lot of times and then I started remembering it, that's how it is.

Could you please explain in layman's terms and in logical way.

Comment: With the `new` _modifier_ you create a method only invokable on the class containing that method. Change `Class1 obj` to `Class2 obj` and it will be called. But I'm quite sure there's a duplicate that perfectly explains that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764382/c-sharp-new-in-method-declaration

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in how method dispatch occurs. When you use `new void Test1()`, you're creating a new, identically named member that simply lexically shadows the original one: if you have a reference of type `Class2 thing`, an invocation of `thing.Test1()` is dispatched to the `Class2.Test1` method, since it hides the original declaration.

If you assign the same object to a reference of type `Class1`, the original declaration is no longer hidden, so invoking `thing.Test1()` on `Class1 thing` will result in `Class1.Test1` being invoked.

When you use `override`, you are not *hiding* the original implementation; the original implementation is simply not available in the derived instance at all. You've *swapped out* the implementation of the original declaration, so regardless of whether you store the object in a reference of type `Class1` or `Class2`, invoking `.Test1()` will use the overriding implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords